# Resaving Entries hitting a mysterious memory limit

Tags: memory, stalled-tasks

I renamed a channel section and Craft (2.6.3012) is trying to resave all the entries therein (about 500 entries, many with up to 10 localized versions). I'm constantly getting this error (in `/craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log`):

```
[26-Mar-2018 15:53:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes) in C:\server\project_x\craft\app\helpers\ModelHelper.php on line 95
```

Here's the thing... in `php.ini`, the `memory_limit` setting is set to `512M`. Not the `256M` one would expect from the error. In Craft's `admin/utils/phpinfo` page, it shows that PHP does indeed have a limit of 512Mb, but the process still hits a mysterious memory limit at 256MB.

I'm running locally on XAMPP, PHP 5.6.24 (switching to PHP 7 prevents me from being able to login for some reason), and this is just part of setting up a site, so I don't care about performance or advisable settings with this issue.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you'll need to add this line to the Craft config file (`craft/config/general.php`)...

```
'phpMaxMemoryLimit' => '512M',
```

- [Craft 2 docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#phpmaxmemorylimit)
- [Craft 3 docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#phpmaxmemorylimit)

Comment: I don't know if there is a behaviour difference between Craft 2 and 3, but reading the Craft 3 docs suggests not specifying `phpMaxMemoryLimit` i.e. null basically means it will try and use the max available anyway, so why set a fixed value?